# How Do I Login To Shopware Version 6.5.1.0 Database on Docker?

Tags: docker, shopware, shopware6

I get the error `Permission denied` on URL `localhost/adminer.php`.
The credentials I use are:

```
System - MYSQL
Server  - Localhost
Username - root
Password - root
Database - shopware
```

How do I log in, I am using running Shopware Version 6.5.1.0 on Docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

```
System - MYSQL
Server  - 127.0.0.1
Username - root
Password - root
Database - shopware
```